# vue.js prop does not get rendered in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am facing an issue with Vue.js prop rendering.
I have two components: `poi-point-adder` one that dynamically creates children forms, and the form child one `poi-component` (that gets created). This is how they look like:

`poi-point-adder`:

```
var poiAdderComponent = Vue.component('poi-point-adder', {
  data: function(){
    return {
      children: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.children.push(poiComponent);
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.children = [];
  },
  template: `
  <div>
      <h1 class="title">Creator</h1>
      <div>
        <template v-for="(child, index) in children">
          <poi-component :id="index"></poi-component>
        </template>
      </div>
      <button class="button is-primary" @click="add()">+</button>
  </div>
  `
});
```

and

`poi-component`:

```
var poiComponent = Vue.component('poi-component', {
    props: {
        index: String
      },
      data: {
      },
      methods: {
      },
    template: `
    <div :poi_index="index">
      <p>Hi n {{index}}</p>
    </div>`
    });
```

The issue occurs with the second one. When I create new instances, the `index` prop does not get rendered (yet `poi_index` is given the right index):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `poi-component` you shouldn't be expecting the prop named `index`, but `id`.

And also: you don't need the `<template></template>` around the component.

**poi-component.vue**

```
var poiComponent = Vue.component('poi-component', {
  props: {
    id: String
  },
  data: {},
  methods: {},
  template: `
    <div :poi_index="id">
      <p>Hi n {{id}}</p>
    </div>`
});
```

**poi-point-adder.vue**

```
var poiAdderComponent = Vue.component('poi-point-adder', {
  data: function(){
    return {
      children: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.children.push(poiComponent);
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.children = [];
  },
  template: `
  <div>
      <h1 class="title">Creator</h1>
      <div>
        <!-- you are passing down the prop "id" with the
        value of "index" -->
        <poi-component
          v-for="(child, index) in children"
          :key="index"
          :id="index"
        ></poi-component>
      </div>
      <button class="button is-primary" @click="add()">+</button>
  </div>
  `
});
```

More on this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

#### Modification

If you make your prop required, you'll see the error/warning message if the passed prop's name is not correct (the example below is OK, so no error should be displayed):

**poi-component.vue**

```
var poiComponent = Vue.component('poi-component', {
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: {},
  methods: {},
  template: `
    <div :poi_index="id">
      <p>Hi n {{id}}</p>
    </div>`
});
```